# Sending error triggered emails to selected admins only

Tags: django, django-errors

When a 500 error occurs on the server, django automatically emails all admins. That is a great feature, but what if some admins want to opt out? Is is possible for admins to choose whether or not they want django to email them when error occurs? Server is logging all errors anyway and data is available for revision to all admins when they log in to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.8 there will be the ability to override who receives an email when an error occurs. It's also possible in earlier Django versions but the code will be uglier.

Django sends the error emails using Python's logging framework and this can be customised ([see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler)). In particular the handler has the following method:

> `send_mail(subject, message, *args, **kwargs):` Sends emails to admin users. To customize this behavior, you can subclass the AdminEmailHandler class and override this method.

This calls `django.core.mail.mail_admins` which by default sends an email to all entries in `settings.ADMINS`. You'll instead need to use [`django.core.mail.send_mail`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/__init__.py) to customise who you wish to send an email (i.e., take `settings.ADMINS`, apply the filtering and call `send_maiL` yourself with the recipient list as desired).